# Change size of camera preview doesn't work (preview picture is stripped)

Tags: android, android-camera

I need to process all frames generated by my camera view in order to read a barcode.

I use an HTC Sensation (i do not have yet another phone to test on it)

So i call getSupportedPreviewSizes to choose the best resolution i can use, and i got :

---

1920,1088

1280,720

960,544

800,480

720,480

640,480

640,368

480,320

352,288

320,240

176,144

---

But only 640x480 works :(

If i use :

parameters.setPreviewSize(800 , 600);

OR

parameters.setPreviewSize(960 , 544);

OR

parameters.setPreviewSize(1280 , 720);

then the picture i got is stripped, i show you an example here :

[image]

If i use set 3264x1840 or 2592x1456 as preview size, it has no effect, the picture generated still has a size of 640x480

If i set 1920x1088 as preview size, i got this fatal erro which the restart the app automatically :

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x417db2d9 (code=2)

For your information, i copy/past the body of my onPreviewFrame :

```
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
    {

    int width = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;  
    int height = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height; 

    Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data , parameters.getPreviewFormat(), width , height , null);

    String resultText = "";

    try 
    {


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0 , 0 , image.getWidth() , image.getHeight()), 100, baos);

        // Convertie YUV TO BITMAP
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( baos.toByteArray(), 0,  baos.size());

        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);

            outStream.close();

            outStream.flush();

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }    

  }
```

I update my post with the code of my surfaceChanged function which include the code for call back buffer :

```
    @Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,  int format, int width, int height) 
{

    try 
    {
        Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    //  parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH); // ACTIVE FLASH SI NECESSAIRE
    //  parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO ); // ACTIVE AUTOFOCURS
    //  parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_STEADYPHOTO);

        String focusMode = Utils.findSettableValue(parameters.getSupportedFocusModes(), Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO, Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO);

        if (focusMode != null) 
        {
            parameters.setFocusMode(focusMode);
        }

        Log.e(TAG , "PREVIEWS : ");

        List<Size> previews = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < previews.size() ; i++) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG , i + " : " + previews.get(i).width + "," + previews.get(i).height);
        } 

        Log.e(TAG , "PICTURES : ");

        List<Size> pictures = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < pictures.size() ; i++) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG , i + " : " + pictures.get(i).width + "," + pictures.get(i).height);
        } 

        Size preview = previews.get(1);

        parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();


//      parameters.setPreviewSize(preview.width , preview.height);

    //  Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(width, height);



        parameters.setPictureSize(1280 , 720);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(1280 , 720);

        camera.setParameters(parameters);

    //  camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        int imgformat = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
        int bitsperpixel = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(imgformat);

        Camera.Size camerasize = parameters.getPreviewSize();
        int frame_size = ((camerasize.width * camerasize.height) * bitsperpixel) / 8;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[frame_size];
        camera.addCallbackBuffer(buffer);



    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

}
```

But even with the callback buffer, the problem remains, the picture is stripped.

Did i do something wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Its probably easiest to use zxing or similar library to read barcodes for you

Comment: I use zxing :), but in API mode, not with intent (as i need to customize the whole view)

Answer (score 1):

What is the size of callback buffer? is it enough to have all preview pixels?

Comment: What do you mean by "callback buffer" ? this variable ? YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data , parameters.getPreviewFormat(), width , height , null); ?

Comment: There isn't the callback buffer in your code shown above. When you set up the camera, you may use 'addcallbackbuffer(byte[] callbackbuffer)'. I think your code has no error. So, check the other code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited my post to include the code which setup the camera (and the callback buffer aswell). But i still get the problem. I guess i don't setup the callback buffer well or i miss something ? thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know what's the problem. :( If you haven't solved it yet, changing the size of the view is one of the consideration. Make the size of the view equal to the preview size.

Comment: I made a mistake in my problem description. In the view displaying camera output, the result is OK. But you can see on my onPreviewFrame that i save all the preview picture in the sdcard. Theses pictures are stripped. Someone told me this : "You're requesting data of a certain size, but treating it as if it were another size. You also seem to be treating the YUV data as RGB, which is why it's all green. You'll probably need to read up a lot more on the API to understand what the byte[] you get back is -- this has at least two significant errors. " But OK when i don't change the preview size).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, HTC G11 has the same problem (setPreviewSize more than 1280x720).

I suggest to adapt HTC phones. If they are using a HTC phone, setPreviewSize to 640x480.